# sort 'like a library' in windows explorer (omit 'The ', 'A ', 'An', etc)

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

Is there a way to sort 'like a library' in windows explorer (omit 'The ', 'A ' and 'An ' from file names for the purpose of sorting)? i.e. current behavior (sorted as Windows would normally do with sort by name):

```
A File 4.ext
A File 2.ext
File 3.ext
File 7.ext
The File 1.ext
The File 5.ext
The File 6.ext
The File 8.ext
The File 9.ext
```

and I want:

```
The File 1.ext
A File 2.ext
File 3.ext
A File 4.ext
The File 5.ext
The File 6.ext
File 7.ext
The File 8.ext
The File 9.ext
```

I do not want to rename my files like this (for aesthetic reasons):

```
File 1, The.ext
File 2, A.ext
File 3.ext
File 4, A.ext
File 5, The.ext
File 6, The.ext
File 7.ext
File 8, The.ext
File 9, The.ext
```

If there is no way to do this in Windows Explorer is there a third party explorer that does this and doesn't look like it came straight out of XP/9x?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will lead you to an immediate solution, but I don't think this is possible in Windows Explorer. [KDE Dolphin](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management) looks like it may do it; you can download Dolphin (and its dependencies) using the [KDE Windows Installer](http://windows.kde.org).

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible using Windows Explorer.

It seems like it used to be possible by creating a column handler shell extension (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776831(v=vs.85).aspx) which you could program to sort according to your needs, but that feature was unfortunately deprecated in Windows Vista.